# what is $# used in a script for?

Tags: shell-script

In many scripts in my organisation and even on online tutorials, this is a common `if` clause I come across :

```
if [ $# -eq "somethng" -o $# -eq "somethng" ]
```

what does this `$#` condition match—some user input by default?
Can this be used on command line directly too??

Comment: In `bash`, see _Special Parameters_ (pp. 8-9) and their expansion (pp. 19...) and finally Conditional Expressions (pp. 28-29) for context.

Comment: Things like `$#` are unfortunately difficult to find in the bash documentation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20272085/827263).

Comment: @KeithThompson : wow...u just gave me a bang-on ref url!!! :D

Comment: @KeithThompson I printed the `bash` manual in booklet form using the [livre](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16265/how-to-control-the-page-parameters-margins-brochurisation-of-man-t-postscr/21902#21902) script. A printed version makes a huge difference for me in this context. As is finding an answer like the one you link to which provides the exact terminology for the concepts at hand.

Comment: @KeithThompson Also newbie here. But IMHO, $ and # should not appear together in the list on special parameters as conceptually expansion should not be confused with the parameters themselves. Contrary to what I read sometimes $ has nothing to do with variables. As you know it expands a parameter, a variable or enables command substitution or arithmetic expansion. There is an entire section about expansion, including of parameters, with examples. Variable is never defined; "word" and "name" are. Prefixing the params with $ would mean prefixing the shell variables in the next section too...

Comment: Actually saying a variable was not defined was wrong as it is defined as a "parameter denoted by a name". But expansion remains unrelated is what I mean here. Anyways, reading this entirely helps but surely it could be more searchable. Maybe there's a way that searching for "$#" could land you in the special params section without having to modify the text.

Comment: Also related: [What does $# mean in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122343/80216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$#` is number of arguments you passed to bash script, not counting `$0`, which is program name.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Number of arguments is: $#"
```

Then run:

```
% cuonglm at ~
% ./test.sh a b c d
Number of arguments is: 4
```

Comment: so it tells me `how` many arguments are there, not `what` arguments are there!!???

Comment: Yes, if you want `what` arguments are there, use `$@` instead.